# change toggle background if checked

Tags: html, css

I want to change the colour of my toggle background as soon as checked. Unfortunately the attempt I tried does not work. I do not want to change the indicator colour! I am aware of the fact, that as soon as I exclude `<input..` from the div, it works. But if I do so the animation doesn´t work any longer. Which would require a huge amount of work in my actually project.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <title>Toggle color</title>
    <!-- d3.js framework -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
    <!-- fontawesome stylesheet https://fontawesome.com/ -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/39094309d6.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<style>

.toggle {
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  width: 60px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow:
    -8px -4px 8px 0px #ffffff,
    8px 4px 12px 0px #d1d9e6,
    4px 4px 4px 0px #d1d9e6 inset,
    -4px -4px 4px 0px #ffffff inset;
}
  
.toggle-state {
    display: none;
}
  
.indicator {
    height: 100%;
    width: 200%;
    background: #ecf0f3;
    border-radius: 15px;
    transform: translate3d(-75%, 0, 0);
    transition: transform 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.85, 0.05, 0.18, 1.35);
    box-shadow:
      -8px -4px 8px 0px #ffffff,
      8px 4px 12px 0px #d1d9e6;
}

.toggle-state:checked ~ .indicator {
    transform: translate3d(25%, 0, 0);
}

.toggle-state:checked + .toggle {
    background-color: greenyellow;
}

</style>

<body>   
    <label> 
        <div class="toggle">
            <input class="toggle-state" type="checkbox" checked/>
            <div class="indicator"></div>
        </div>
    </label>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Adjacent Sibling Selector `+` in `.toggle-state:checked + .toggle {` will not change its parent's `background-color` if I remember correctly

Comment: @HuyPhạm correct, thats why it is working as soon as I exclude the <input.. from the div. I mentioned it in the question. But still a got hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Not the best answer tho, but this is best I can do without JS, just play round and improve CSS here and there, it will be fine.**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <title>Toggle color</title>
    <!-- d3.js framework -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
    <!-- fontawesome stylesheet https://fontawesome.com/ -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/39094309d6.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<style>

.toggle {
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  width: 60px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow:
    -8px -4px 8px 0px #ffffff,
    8px 4px 12px 0px #d1d9e6,
    4px 4px 4px 0px #d1d9e6 inset,
    -4px -4px 4px 0px #ffffff inset;
}
  
.toggle-background {
    position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  width: 60px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: red;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
 
.toggle-state {
    display: none;
}
  
.indicator {
    height: 100%;
    width: 200%;
    background: #ecf0f3;
    border-radius: 15px;
    transform: translate3d(-75%, 0, 0);
    transition: transform 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.85, 0.05, 0.18, 1.35);
    box-shadow:
      -8px -4px 8px 0px #95f700,
      8px 4px 12px 0px darkred;
}

.toggle-state:checked ~ .indicator {
    transform: translate3d(25%, 0, 0);
}

.toggle-state:checked + .toggle {
    background-color: greenyellow;
}



.toggle-state:checked ~ .toggle-background {
    background-color: greenyellow;
}

</style>

<body>   
    <label> 
        <div class="toggle">
            <input class="toggle-state" type="checkbox" checked/>
              <div class="toggle-background">
            </div>
            <div class="indicator"></div>
          
        </div>
    </label>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some JS code for listening the checked event of the checkbox,

create two different style class if checked or unchecked

like bellow

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <title>Toggle color</title>
    <!-- d3.js framework -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
    <!-- fontawesome stylesheet https://fontawesome.com/ -->
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/39094309d6.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </head>

  <style>
    .toggle {
      position: absolute;
      height: 30px;
      width: 60px;
      border-radius: 15px;
      overflow: hidden;
      cursor: pointer;
      box-shadow: -8px -4px 8px 0px #ffffff, 8px 4px 12px 0px #d1d9e6,
        4px 4px 4px 0px #d1d9e6 inset, -4px -4px 4px 0px #ffffff inset;
    }

    .toggle-state {
      display: none;
    }

    .indicator {
      height: 100%;
      width: 200%;
      background: #ecf0f3;
      border-radius: 15px;
      transform: translate3d(-75%, 0, 0);
      transition: transform 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.85, 0.05, 0.18, 1.35);
      box-shadow: -8px -4px 8px 0px #ffffff, 8px 4px 12px 0px #d1d9e6;
    }

    .green {
      background-color: greenyellow;
    }

    .black {
      background-color: black;
    }

    .toggle-state:checked ~ .indicator {
      transform: translate3d(25%, 0, 0);
    }

    .toggle-state:checked > .indicator {
      background-color: greenyellow;
    }
  </style>

  <body>
    <label>
      <div class="toggle">
        <input id="mycheckbox" class="toggle-state" type="checkbox" />
        <div id="indicateit" class="indicator"></div>
      </div>
    </label>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var cb = document.getElementById("mycheckbox");
      cb.addEventListener("change", function (e) {
        console.log("Changed ");
        if (this.checked) {
          document.getElementById("indicateit").classList.remove("black");
          document.getElementById("indicateit").classList.add("green");
        } else {
          document.getElementById("indicateit").classList.remove("green");
          document.getElementById("indicateit").classList.add("black");
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Good solution but it would require to create separate ID´s for each toggle. In dependency how huge your project is, it gets messy pretty quick.

Comment: use `querySelectorAll` and `forEach` and it would work on all toggles

Answer (score 0):

**Could this work for you? I haven't tried it on multiple buttons...**

Basically, just added an onchange event to your input. It calls a function that gets the input's parent, gets `--onColor` and `--offColor` variables from the CSS (.toggle class) and sets the background.

*Note: If you decide to use this, you'll probably want to modify the CSS a bit to make the shadows look better and maybe add a transition to the color change.*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <title>Toggle color</title>
    <!-- d3.js framework -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
    <!-- fontawesome stylesheet https://fontawesome.com/ -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/39094309d6.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<style>

.toggle {
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  width: 60px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow:
    -8px -4px 8px 0px #ffffff,
    8px 4px 12px 0px #d1d9e6,
    4px 4px 4px 0px #d1d9e6 inset,
    -4px -4px 4px 0px #ffffff inset;
  --onColor:green;
  --offColor:red;
}
  
.toggle-state {
    display: none;
}
  
.indicator {
    height: 100%;
    width: 200%;
    background: #ecf0f3;
    border-radius: 15px;
    transform: translate3d(-75%, 0, 0);
    transition: transform 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.85, 0.05, 0.18, 1.35);
    box-shadow:
      -8px -4px 8px 0px #ffffff,
      8px 4px 12px 0px #d1d9e6;
}

.toggle-state:checked ~ .indicator {
    transform: translate3d(25%, 0, 0);
}

.toggle-state:checked + .toggle {
    background-color: greenyellow;
}

</style>

<script>
function changeToggleBg(el)  {
    const toggle = el.parentElement;
    let onColor = getComputedStyle(toggle).getPropertyValue('--onColor');
    let offColor = getComputedStyle(toggle).getPropertyValue('--offColor');
    toggle.style.backgroundColor = (toggle.style.backgroundColor == offColor.replace(' ','')) ? onColor : offColor;
}
</script>

<body>   
    <label> 
        <div class="toggle">
            <input class="toggle-state" type="checkbox" onchange="changeToggleBg(this)" checked/>
            <div class="indicator"></div>
        </div>
    </label>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it is a bad use to change the style through `.style` functions. This willa dd the style through inline-style which has the 2nd highest specificty weight. as such it can cause a variety of issues. The smarter solution is to use JS to add/remove classes (classList.add/classList.remove) which will maintain the normal specificty weight.